# Unit Testing - verify method called

Tags: mocking, junit4, verify

I am unit testing a method that takes an object as parameter A, creates an instance of another object, B and populates B's properties with A's. The code then calls a method on a separate class called messageSender.send(B);

I need to verify that send() is called. I have tried the following but it fails saying sendBMessage was called with a different type of B object.

Anyone any idea how to verify messageSender.send(B) is called?

```
 class MyMailSender{
    MessageSender messageSender;

    void sendBMessage(Object A){
       B b = new B();
       b.setId(A.getId()):

       messageSender.send(B);

    }

class test{
 @Mock
 private MessageSender messageSender;
 @InjectMocks
 MyMailSender myMailSender;

 void testSendB(){
   A a = new A();
   a.setId(100);

   B b = new B();
   b.setId(a.getId());

   myMailSender.sendBMessage(a);

   verify(messageSender).send(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works:

```
    verify(messageSender).send(any(B.class));
```